# How to add email to Stripe custom form for receipts (error: Received unknown parameter: email)

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, email, stripe-payments

How do I add an email input so that Stripe can send out receipts? It looks like it's not a valid Charge argument, as from

```
try: 
    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
      amount=1000, #cents
      email=email,
      currency="usd",
      card=token
    )
except stripe.CardError, e: #card declined
    pass
```

I get an error saying

```
Received unknown parameter: email
```

How do I send the email argument to Stripe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a customer with the email address and card and then pass the customer to the charge:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.create(
  card=token,
  email=email
)
charge = stripe.Charge.create(
  customer=customer.id,
  amount=1000,
  currency="usd"
)
```

Comment: Oh...I figured out I had to make a customer object, but I thought the card token had to be a charge argument